# I can't reference variables of a class

Tags: c#

I declared the test class as public on top of the Form1 class.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public class test
    {
        public double a { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    class Class1
    {
       test tx = new test();
       tx.a = 100;        
    }
}
```

I created Class1.cs and created a test instance.
An attempt was made to reference tx.a but failed.

What do I need to do to refer to test?

Comment: You cannot just write `tx.a = 100;` in your class. You have to place that kind of code in something like a method or constructor.

Comment: You cannot add a class above a form class or the designer will not know how to parse and draw the form the next time you open it.  Also, `a` is not a variable, but a *property*

Comment: I suppose you could write `test tx = new test { a = 100 };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a constructor or a method. You cannot update a property of the class without an instance of the class (created by invoking the class constructor)

If you make test a property of the class, you can access it over all methods of the class. Add a getter to it, and then you can access it from all instances of the class

```
class Class1
{
   private test tx = new test();
   public Class1() {
       tx.a = 100;        
   } 
}
```

Note: classes should start with capital letters, and `a` should be private, otherwise the getter and setter are pointless